# Inconsistent sorting by row color

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have a sub that highlights each row based on the cell value found within a specific column range, then it uses the below code to sort each row by its cell color in a specific color order. The color part of the sub is done using a FindAllOccurrences function and if formulas found on this question [Sorting and color-coding based on variables](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93361/sorting-and-color-coding-based-on-variables). The issue I am having is with the sort function. In its current form, it works, but not absolutely. What I mean is, the last color is red that is only used to highlight discontinued items on my sheet, the sort function is supposed to sort this last, which it does if its there, if it isn't there, it seems to override the color to make the last color on my sheet red regardless on if its discontinued. I have tested it by changing different variables, and I am getting different results.

It could be something I'm not seeing, but the only thing that seems to fit as to why it is inconsistent is that the sort function doesn't contain an if command. Meaning nothing in the code allows it to skip if the color isn't found. I assumed that because it was a sort function that it couldn't sort a color that wasn't there so it would auto-skip to the next color that was found, but maybe I was incorrect? Any suggestions?

```
 Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 Set LastRow = WS.Range("FU3:FU5002")
 With WS.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear

    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(204, 255, 255)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(102, 0, 102)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(204, 255, 204)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(128, 128, 0)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(150, 150, 150)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(204, 204, 255)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 128, 128)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(102, 102, 153)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(128, 0, 0)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(128, 0, 128)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 102, 204)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 153, 204)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(204, 153, 255)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(153, 51, 102)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(153, 204, 0)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 204, 255)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(51, 153, 102)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(51, 51, 153)
    .SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    .SetRange DataSheet
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: That is an interesting idea, I didn't know that was possible.  Could you go into greater details in an answer? Is it possible, with this method you have in mind, to specify an order of priority? This is not absolutely necessary, but would be ideal if possible.

Comment: I think it might get too complicated trying to retrieve RGB - sorry. Removed my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, I'm saying "here's an answer to a question you didn't ask" because I don't know *why* excel is doing that, but since I brought it up in a comment, I'll post it. I don't imagine it's a **good** way of doing this.

Read the unique colors into a dictionary and convert them to an array of RGB

Then I guess add the filter for each `sortfield` - but that would be ridiculous as I imagine you have a color scheme you want. So instead, maybe take the order of your colors and compare each to see if it's in the array, and if so, do the sort. Otherwise, skip the color?

```
Sub test()
Dim col As Variant

Dim d As Object
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each c In Range("FU3:FU5002")
    col = (c.Interior.Color)
    d(col) = 1
Next
Dim v As Variant
Dim j As Integer
j = d.Count
Dim colores() As String
ReDim colores(j)
i = 1
For Each v In d.keys
    colores(i) = Convert_Dec2RGB(v)
    i = i + 1
Next

'With ActiveSheet.Sort
    'For k = 1 To j
    '.SortFields.Add(LastRow, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                    SortOnValue.Color = colores(k)
    'Next
'End With

End Sub

Private Function Convert_Dec2RGB(ByVal myDECIMAL As Long) As String
'https://socko.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/convert-decimal-to-rgb-color-value/
  Dim myRED As Long
  Dim myGREEN As Long
  Dim myBLUE As Long

  myRED = myDECIMAL And &HFF
  myGREEN = (myDECIMAL And &HFF00&) \ 256
  myBLUE = myDECIMAL \ 65536

  Convert_Dec2RGB = "RGB(" & CStr(myRED) & "," & CStr(myGREEN) & "," & CStr(myBLUE) & ")"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code.
You have to find all the color codes you want to sort and add that color code for soting inorder which you want.

Sub test()

```
Dim dis As Object

Set dis = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

P = 1
Rcnt = Range("AU65000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To Rcnt
    On Error Resume Next
    dis.Add Range("A" & i).Interior.Color, P
    P = P + 1
Next i

'sorting
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
'red
If dis.exists(255) = True Then ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A2:A10"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = 255
'yellow
If dis.exists(65535) = True Then ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A2:A10"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = 65535
'blue
If dis.exists(12874308) = True Then ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A2:A10"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = 12874308
'orange
If dis.exists(3243501) = True Then ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A2:A10"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = 3243501
'green
If dis.exists(5287936) = True Then ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A2:A10"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = 5287936
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:A10")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Range("A1").Select
```

End Sub